# jquery accordion image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, jquery-plugins

I am trying to include the arrow icon into my accordion...
i dont know how to write css for this combined images
here is my image links http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png

here is my js code

http://jsfiddle.net/Uf7Nj/3/

```
/*!
 * Vallenato 1.0
 * A Simple JQuery Accordion
 *
 * Designed by Switchroyale
 * 
 * Use Vallenato for whatever you want, enjoy!
 */

$(document).ready(function()
{
    //Add Inactive Class To All Accordion Headers
    $('.accordion-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');

    //Set The Accordion Content Width
    var contentwidth = $('.accordion-header').width();
    $('.accordion-content').css({'width' : contentwidth });



    // The Accordion Effect
    $('.accordion-header').click(function () {
        if($(this).is('.inactive-header')) {
            $('.active-header').toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header').next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        }

        else {
            $(this).toggleClass('active-header').toggleClass('inactive-header');
            $(this).next().slideToggle().toggleClass('open-content');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

​

Comment: @Scorpio lol stone age here ?

Comment: @Scorpio: but here they have used whole image http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just extract needed icon positions from [jquery-ui css](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css):

CSS:

```
.ui-icon { 
    width: 16px; 
    height: 16px; 
    background-image: url("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png");
}
      

        
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n { background-position: 0 -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-ne { background-position: -16px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-e { background-position: -32px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-se { background-position: -48px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s { background-position: -64px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-sw { background-position: -80px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-w { background-position: -96px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-1-nw { background-position: -112px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s { background-position: -128px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-ne-sw { background-position: -144px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-e-w { background-position: -160px -48px; }
.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-se-nw { background-position: -176px -48px; }
```

[sample](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/Uf7Nj/10/)

to get a name of icon go to [theme rolling page](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)
hover on icon you need, open css file, find  a names for icon there, copy code to your new css.

Comment: I see only one image is it possible to include two different images

Comment: you mean two different icons ?

Comment: how to see chnge of image for each click

Comment: can you tell me how to do it...i will do

Comment: in your `$('.accordion-header').click(function () {` switch the class of icon div